# Need to add DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn in a Winform Application

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need to put a Checkbox against each Row in a DataGridView. I am making use of DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn for the purpose. But here user is able to select more than 1 row. How to restrict the user from selecting multiple rows in a DataGridView?

Comment: is the question: "how do I stop the user selecting multiple rows in a DataGridView?" ... if so, might you rephrase the title?

Comment: well, Yes. When user selects a row having selected another one, the previous one should be unchecked and the current row should be checked. Thanks

Comment: hi @Ananth i still think your title, question and this comment could be consolidated into an improved q. I don't have the rep to do it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to do it yourself when the checkbox is checked.

> If you want to respond immediately
>   when users click a check box cell, you
>   can handle the
>   DataGridView.CellContentClick event,
>   but this event occurs before the cell
>   value is updated. If you need the new
>   value at the time of the click, one
>   option is to calculate what the
>   expected value will be based on the
>   current value. Another approach is to
>   commit the change immediately, and
>   handle the
>   DataGridView.CellValueChanged event to
>   respond to it. To commit the change
>   when the cell is clicked, you must
>   handle the
>   DataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
>   event. In the handler, if the current
>   cell is a check box cell, call the
>   DataGridView.CommitEdit method and
>   pass in the Commit value.

Whichever method you use, when you handle the checkbox being checked, you will need to mark all the other checkboxes as unchecked. How you will do that depends on whether (and how) your DataGridView is data-bound.

Comment: +1 i think this answers the Q as i understand it (from piecing together edited Q and his comment)